# What's the best way to display data with more than 1 variable in a table?

Tags: r, database-design

I have the following data.

[image]

I'm trying to find the best way to visualise this data in a table format (in R) but I can't seem to find an option that is easy to read or makes comparison easy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pivot (reshape) it into an "untidy" or wide format (but easily readable) so that there is one row for each country, and N columns, where Score and GDP are nested within the years. This should be ok if there are not too many years (<5 say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in df1, the following command reshapes it to a wide format:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Country, 
              names_from = Year, 
              values_from=c(Score, GDP))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  Country Score_2015 Score_2016 Score_2017 Score_2018 Score_2019 GDP_2015 GDP_2016 GDP_2017 GDP_2018 GDP_2019
  <fct>        <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1 Afghan           1          3          5          7          9      101      103      105      107      109
2 Swiss            2          4          6          8         10      102      104      106      108      110
```

---

Which looks quite wide, but with better formatting, can be made to look like this:

[image]

---

**Data**:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Country=rep(c("Afghan","Swiss"),5),
                 Year=rep(2015:2019, each=2),
                 Score=c(1:10), GDP=101:110)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! Any chance you could explain how to get it to look like that in R? I've tried using kableExtra but without any luck.

Comment: I'm afraid that is a totally new question. Best to start a new one. The title could be: "How to make R output look prettier" or something similar. But I'm sure there are lots of answers already out there. Try searching... if you don't see anything, start a new question. ;)